# Windows Phone Runtime API VibrationDevice pattern

Tags: c#, timer, windows-phone-8.1, scheduled-tasks, vibration

On `VibrationDevice` MSDN page there is an information about `TimeSpan` limit:

> Vibrates the phone for the specified duration (from 0 to 5 seconds).

Is there any way to overcome this limit, that is, to let device vibrate longer than 5 seconds?

Also, there is a feature when developing on **android** devices, that lets you deliver the pattern in which the phone will vibrate.

```
public void vibrate (long[] pattern, int repeat)
```

I would like to implement similar behavior with Windows Phone Runtime API. My concept is to use `Timer` or `Task.Delay`. Is this a good idea? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to exceed the limit of 5 seconds. If you want to use some kind of pattern you need to implement that by yourself. 
But make sure, that you make this implementation `async` if you use the `Task.Delay`, so your App won't freeze. 
Maybe try something like this:

```
public async void Vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat)
    {
        var vd = VibrationDevice.GetDefault();
        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
        {
            foreach (var x in pattern)
            {
                vd.Vibrate(new TimeSpan(x));
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just elaborating over Rafael Regh's answer, here is my solution handling also the length of the pause between vibrations.

The implementation recognises that vd.Vibrate() just starts vibration and does not stop code stepping.. ..so Task.Delay() must take into account also vibration length to achieve its purpose of actually setting a pause in between vibrations !

```
public static async Task PatternVibrate(
    long[] millisecPattern,
    long millisecPause,
    int repetitions)
    {
        var vd = VibrationDevice.GetDefault();
        for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++)
        {
            foreach (var millisec in millisecPattern)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Vibrating {0} millisec..", millisec));
                vd.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisec));
                await Task.Delay((int)millisec + (int)millisecPause);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can be used like this:

```
await PatternVibrate(new long[] {500, 500, 1000 }, 100, 1);
```